# Are the GBA enhancements accessible in the NSO versions of the Oracles games?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online, zelda-oracle-of-ages, zelda-oracle-of-seasons

Nintendo just released the Oracles games to it's Game Boy - Nintendo Switch Online app. These games had special enhancements if you were playing them on a physical GBA.

Does anyone know if these GBA enhancements are accessible in these versions of the game?

In these games, there were special "advance" shops that allowed you to buy powerful rings and Gasha Seeds.

Here's where the advance shop is in Oracle of Seasons:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it is. Playing through Oracle of Seasons at the beginning, the door to  the shop is closed. I don't remember if it was only closed at the start of the game and opens later, but as far as I can tell, it's not available. It wasn't even available in the 3ds versions either. I'd imagine it's the same case for Oracle of Ages.

[image]